# Converting from float to percentage

Tags: python, format

I would like to convert a decimal number (say 0.33333) to percentage (expected answer 33.33%)

I used the following

```
x = 0.3333

print(format(x,'.2%'))
```

which gives indeed 33.33%

However, the result is a string, I would like it to still be a number (in % format) to be able to perform mathematical operations on it (e.g. `format(x,'.2%')*2` to give 66.66%

But this throws an exception as 33.33% is a string

Comment: Umm... `x * 100` ?

Comment: sure, but I was looking for a figure to have % in it, much like in Excel where you have % but you can still perform mathematical operations on it

Comment: Python is not excel. Excel is adding that `%` when it's showing the number to you. Internally it's still storing it as a number. You can't have it both ways. A `%` doesn't belong in a number.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try and find a way to display it in % while still storing it as a number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An idea is to create a custom datatype, I'll call it `Percent`, which inherit everything from `float`, but when you want to use it as a string it shows a `%` and multiplies the number with 100.

```
class Percent(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{:.2%}'.format(self)
x = Percent(0.3333)
print(x)
# 33.33%
```

If you want to represnt the value in envoirment like jupyter notebook in your format you can add same method with the name `__repr__` to Percent Class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{:.2%}'.format(self)
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
x = 0.3333

print('{:,.2%}'.format(x))  # Prints percentage format, retains x as float variable
```

Output:

```
33.33%
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it on a single line like:

```
x = 0.333
print(str(int(x*100)) + "%)
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants it to remain a **number**.  If I store that printed value in a variable, I can not do `percentage * 2` simply because that is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Use f-strings! (python >= 3.6)

`x = 0.3333`

`print(f"{x:,.2%}")`

That is: print x, to 2 decimal places, and add the `%` symbol at the end. x is not altered by the f-string. Add the percent-symbol at the very end. Meaning, do your math with `x` first, then display it however you want with the f-string.